# Simple function call in C# GUI

Tags: c#, function

I'm new to C#. I have two textboxes in a form and a button. When I click the button, I want the value 1 to be put into textbox1 and then the squareroot calculated and put into textbox2. I then want the code to loop for each number between 1-20 and place the respective values in the textboxes. I am simply writing this code just to get used to function calls. My code is below but it doesn't seem to do anything:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int initialVal = 1; initialVal >= 20; initialVal++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = initialVal.ToString();
                int sum = calculation(initialVal);
                textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        static int calculation(int x)
        {
            int sum;
            while (x <= 20)
            {
                sum = x * x;
                x++;
                return sum;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1)

```
for (int initialVal = 1; initialVal >= 20; initialVal++)
```

This will never do anything because the exit condition is met - you probably meant `initialVal <= 20`

2) You need to use a background thread  - otherwise your GUI won't update until your button1`_`Click handler is completely finished. E.g. have a look at the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: Great eye. Easily overlooked.

Comment: Thanks @DennisTraub. It seems to run no problem now but only prints the value "20" once complete. This is no doubt down to what you suggested and background threads sound far too advanced for me at this stage but I'm glad I now know the answer. Thanks

Comment: Then do your experiments in a simple console app, and do a Console.Writeline() to print the number and squares.

Comment: @thefragileomen You can do `Application.DoEvents()` right before the `Sleep` as a lazy man's way to update the GUI if you don't feel like getting into threading.  However running a background thread will be a little better because even if you use `DoEvents` your GUI will be non-responsive during each of the `Sleep` calls.  Not a big deal for 500 ms intervals, but if you sleep for much longer it can be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop will never be executed since its condition is not satisfied:

```
initialVal >= 20
```

Change it to

```
initialVal <= 20
```

to execute the loop 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop as suggested by others.

And, for this line, I think you can simply do

```
int sum = initialVal * initialVal ;
```

You don't need the calculate to square a number, and that function doesn't do anything meaningful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Sleep` in the GUI can make your app unresponsive, so it's better to use a background thread or a timer.  A timer is easier.  First, in design view, just drag and drop a Timer (it's in the Components section of your toolbox) onto the form.  Set the `Interval` property to 500.  Then double-click it, and put your update code in there.  Note you don't need the loop; you just need some code to tell it to increment `initialVal` with each tick and stop at 20:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Text = initialVal.ToString();
        int sum = calculation(initialVal);
        textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();
        if (initialVal++ == 20)
            timer1.Enabled = false; 
    }
```

Now change your button_click code to simply kick of the timer:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        initialVal = 1;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Finally make `initialVal` as a member variable since both functions need access to it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    int initialVal;
```